# Protobuf not producing API I want

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I'm trying to use *protobufs* to help serialize my data, however when I run the protobuf command on a .proto file, it doesn't provide me with the functions that it says it would,

namely *serializeToString*, and *parseFromString*.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what platform / language are you targeting? The API may be different for different platforms

Comment: targeting C++ on a linux ubuntu platform

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you are targeting C++ (even though the question is tagged protobuf.js).

The generated file will have classes that inherit from the protobuf base class:

```
class MyMessage : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
...
}
```

The `SerializeToString()` (note that it is case-sensitive, with big S) method comes from this base class. You can see all the base class methods [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite).

So just try to use the method from your code and it should be available, even though it is not directly defined in the generated `.pb.h` file.